# Formula Query For Selecting all tables from database

Tags: sql, postgresql

My Data is taken from two table from PostGreSQL
This is one table

```
wv1           rv1
341.6         2.48
343.6         2.58
344.7         2.37
346.3         2.32
347.9         2.29
349.5         2.36
351.1         2.23
352.6         2.24
354.2         2.25
355.8         2.29
357.4         2.28
358.9         2.23
```

Another table as

```
wv2        rv2
341.6      8.24
343.1      8.17
344.7      8.19
346.3      8.13
347.9      8.14
349.5      8.09
351.1      8.09
352.6      8.13
354.2      8.21
355.8      8.24
357.4      8.27
358.9      8.29
```

I am using the data rv1 and rv2
The formula is **

- I = ACOS[rv1.rv2/|rv1|.|rv2|]

**
that is
 **

- I = Acos[((2.38*8.24)+(2.58*8.17)+(2.37*8.19)+.....)/sqrt((2.38*2.38)+(2.58*2.58)+(2.37*2.37)+....)*sqrt((8.24*8.24)+(8.17*8.17)+(8.19*8.19)+....)]

**
PostGreSQL Query for this one is

```
select
    acos(sum(t1.rv1 * t2.rv2) / (
        sqrt(sum(power(t1.rv1, 2))) * sqrt(sum(power(t2.rv2, 2)))
    )) as i
from
    t1
    inner join
    t2 on t1.wv1 = t2.wv2
```

In this Query i want to compare all the tables in the database instead of table2(t2)

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='public' and table_type='BASE TABLE' ORDER BY table_name ASC;";
```

***Final Output***

```
   Ivalue
   0.3559772512926 
   0.52684312
```

I want to write the formula in PostGreSQL query, How to write it, Please guide me...

Comment: The `spec_anle` function code does not match your text. Wouldn't the function name be `spec_angle`? Those things makes people think that you don't know what you want so any effort put in an answer would be rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    acos(sum(t1.rv1 * t2.rv2) / (
        sqrt(sum(power(t1.rv1, 2))) * sqrt(sum(power(t2.rv2, 2)))
    )) as i
from
    t1
    inner join
    t2 on t1.wv1 = t2.wv2
```

`wv1` and `wv2` must be `unique` for this to work

Comment: Thank You Very Much, Mr.Clodoaldo Neto. Its Working Fine